# How to get a running total of a decimal in a query?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code:

```
decimal orderTot;
var orderTotalQry = from ot in conn.Table<orderDetails>()
                                where ot.ORDERNUMBER == orderDetailOrderNumber
                                select ot;

            foreach (orderDetails OD in orderTotalQry)
            {
                orderTot =+ Convert.ToDecimal(OD.ITEMCOST);

            };
```

I am trying to get the orderTot sum of the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

First it should be:

```
orderTot += Convert.ToDecimal(OD.ITEMCOST);
```

and not

```
orderTot =+ Convert.ToDecimal(OD.ITEMCOST); //notice the `+` after `=`
```

Otherwise you can also use LINQ Sum like:

```
var sum = orderTotalQry.Sum(r=> r.ITEMCOST);
```

If `ITEMCOST` is not of type `decimal` then you can explicitly convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ `Sum` method.

```
var sum= orderTotalQry.Sum(f => Convert.ToDecimal(f));
```

Assuming items in `orderTotalQry` is of non numeric type (Ex : String)

If items in orderTotalQry  is of type `decimal`/`int`, you do not need the `Convert.ToDecimal` call.

```
var sum= orderTotalQry.Sum();
```

Or you can use the Sum method in the original statement

```
var total= (from ot in conn.Table<orderDetails>()
                                where ot.ORDERNUMBER == orderDetailOrderNumber
                                select ot).Sum();
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'HDW_Order.Models.orderDetails' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'HDW_Order.Models.orderDetails' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: What does `conn.Table<orderDetails>()` returns ?

Comment: Its a SQLite database table: 
[Table("orderDetailsSurface")]
    public class orderDetails
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ITEMSEQ { get; set; }
        public string ITEMNUM { get; set; }
        public string ITEMQTY { get; set; }
        public string ITEMDESC { get; set; }
        public string ITEMCOST { get; set; }
        public string ITEMSTATUS { get; set; }
        public string ORDERNUMBER { get; set; }

    }

Comment: You did not answer me yet. What is the type returned by this expression `conn.Table<orderDetails>()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using linq methods you can write your query like this:

```
var orderTot = conn.Table<orderDetails>()
                   .Where(o => o.ORDERNUMBER == orderDetailOrderNumber)
                   .Sum(o => o.ITEMCOST);
```